# Why is the resistor necessary?

Tags: voltage, power, resistors

First of all, I am new to the field of electrical engineering (in fact, my knowledge on the topic was almost equal to zero before doing the project), so what I am confused of may seem ridiculous.

I am doing a project on microbial fuel cell and I am asking if the resistor is necessary. In all of the previous projects done there was a resistor, but it just seemed like such a natural thing to use the resistor that I find it confusing. If the resistor was not used all throughout the experiment, will the experimental accuracy be decreased or does it not matter?

(I am not connecting the electric wire to a LED light bulb but a multimeter)

Comment: What resistor??

Comment: Please provide more details. Can you draw a schematic of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When testing a fuel cell for voltage, the DMM is 10MOhm so no resistor in series is needed. THis is V open circuit or Voc.

But to measure power then you need to apply a resistor in parallel aka. shunt so that the voltage drops something like 10% then 20% which thus draws I=V/R and produces P=VI power.

If the fuel cell is a voltage source, maximum power will be at 50% Voc.

But if the fuel cell is like a photocell or current source, then its maximum power will be somewhere around 80% Voc +10%,-20% or more with low input.

Comment: so can I just measure the voltage?

Comment: Voltage potential is just one measure.  Current is need to compute power. But I don't know what you need.

Comment: I just have to show the increase or decrease of voltage/current/power.

Comment: Then you need to measure both V & I.